# Fastest way to add consecutive groups of vector elements in C++

Tags: c++, vector, sum

I have a vector of 120 elements.  I need the sum of each set of 20 values (for a total of 6 sets).  I am currently using two nested for loops, like so:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 120; j+=20) 
    for (int i = j; i < (j +20); i++)
        sum += vector[i]
        code where I use the sum
```

What better (and faster) ways exist to do this using only STL?

Comment: In my opinion, 6 different for loops, each for 20 elements, would be faster.  Because this will be `O(n)`; while your loops are `O(n^2)`.

Comment: @BatCoder, it is not `O(n^2)`. In the first loop the OP is using, `j += 20`.

Comment: You forgot `sum = 0` before inner loop

Comment: There's no such way as a "fastest way" to do anything without a LOT more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the standard library *probably* won't make much (if any) difference here, but it can make probably make the code a little neater:

```
auto const stride = 20;

for (auto b = vec.begin(); b < vec.end(); b+=stride) {
    auto sum = std::accumulate(b, b+stride, 0);
    use(sum);
}
```

Comment: Division is a terribly slow operation.  Besides, the compiler may be unable to optimize away `vector.size()/stride`, if it is not sure that vector.size() does not change within the loop.  Six divisions can easily take more time than 114 additions.  Even one division would be costly.

Comment: @user31264: Good point about the repetition. If he's really certain the size will always be 120, it's trivial to eliminate the division, but I'd have to be *extremely* desperate for the extra speed to take a chance on incorrect behavior if the size changes to save ~20 clock cycles.

Comment: @user31264: After some thought, I've eliminated the division but still retained correct behavior.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can save 6 additions:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 120; j += 20) {
    auto sum = vector[j];
    for (int i = j + 1; i < j + 20; i++)
        sum += vector[i];
    // code which uses the sum
}
```

Second, you can use std::accumulate in hope that your implementation can somehow optimize it:

```
auto it = vector.cbegin();
for (int j = 0; j < 120; j += 20) {
    auto itNext = it + 20;
    auto sum = std::accumulate(it + 1, itNext, *it);
    // code which uses the sum
    it = itNext;
}
```

Note however that, unless `vector` is in cache memory, these or any other improvements will be miniscule at best.  In this case, reading the vector from RAM takes much, much longer then the arithmetics.